# JS: blending two classes

Tags: javascript, class, abstract-class, subclass, apollo-server

Using [Apollo server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/), have a pretty standard setup:

In an `index.js` file that manages my Apollo server state:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const databaseAPI = require('../database/database.datasource');
...
module.exports = new ApolloServer({
    ...
    dataSources: () => {
        return {
            databaseAPI: new databaseAPI()
        };
    },
    ...
});
```

And then my `database.datasource.js` file:

```
const { RESTDataSource } = require("apollo-datasource-rest");

// imports and config here

class databaseAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

// methods here like createUser({email, password, name})

}

module.exports = databaseAPI;
```

This `database.datasource.js` file is getting a bit lengthy, in part because it is managing the db layer for many types, so I was thinking about how to refactor it.

I want to break it apart by major types using a [repository pattern](https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/), something like:

`UserRepository.js` (and similar abstract classes as reference and to enforce an internal API)

```
class UserRepository {

  createUser({ email, password, name }) {
    throw new Error("Not implemented");
  }

  ...

}

export default UserRepository;
```

and then implementations of these in by-type directories:

`/UserRepository/db.datasource.js`

```
import UserRepository from "../UserRepository";
import utils from './utils';

class UserDatabaseAPI extends UserRepository {
  constructor(db) {
    super();
    this.db = db;
  }

  createUser({ email, password, name }) {
    // logic here
  }
}

export default UserDatabaseAPI;
```

My question is how best to manage the multiple classes inside of my root `database.datasource.js` file with multiple inheritance sources.

I could see doing something like this:

```
const { RESTDataSource } = require("apollo-datasource-rest");
const UserDatabaseAPI = require("./UserRepository/db.datasource.js");
// imports and config here, including a db instance

const userDBAPI = new UserDatabaseAPI(db);

class databaseAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

createUser = userDBAPI.createUser;
...

}
```

Though I think that this might become kind of a headache. Is there another approach that might work better here, or is there at least a way to better map the methods in my `userDBAPI` instance to methods in my root `database.datasource.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a single `RESTDataSource` for the endpoint you're wrapping, you can split it up into multiple `RESTDataSource` instances, one per resource. For example, `https://swapi.co/api` can be split into 6 difference `RESTDataSource` instances with the following `baseURL`s:

- https://swapi.co/api/people
- https://swapi.co/api/films
- https://swapi.co/api/starships
- https://swapi.co/api/vehicles
- https://swapi.co/api/species
- https://swapi.co/api/planets

And your config would look something like:

```
dataSources: () => ({
  people: new PeopleAPI(),
  films: new FilmsAPI(),
  starships: new StarshipsAPI(),
  vehicles: new VehiclesAPI(),
  species: new SpeciesAPI(),
  planets: new PlanetsAPI(),
})
```

Comment: Makes sense, but then I have an issue with setting up APIs that inherit from my abstract class while also extending the `RESTDataSource`, no?

Comment: JavaScript classes do not support multiple inheritance. You can have your repository class extend `RESTDataSource` if you want. In my opinion, you're not really gaining much by implementing an additional class, though -- `RESTDataSource` already serves as a level of abstraction between your application and the underlying data source.